# Node NPM Install Error typechecker@2.0.8 preinstall

Tags: node.js, npm

When running `npm install --only=production` when deploying to EC2 CodeDeploy is failing with the following log.

```
[stdout]> typechecker@2.0.8 preinstall /home/ubuntu/node/node_modules/.staging/typechecker-58aa0eda
[stdout]> node ./cyclic.js
line 17: 20390 Killed                   npm install --only=production
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined
```

The only thing I changed was updating my NPM packages and updating Node. But also my rollbacks are now failing.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved in NPM version 5.5.0 or something looks like. [Here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18520) is the official NPM bug.